# Do I need JSON/AJAX when using JSF?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsf

I'm working on a new project based entirely on Java EE 6 technologies, including JSF/EJB/JPA. In previous projects I widely used json/ajax before. But this time I'm reconsidering if I really need json/ajax any more. JSF has supplied me with a great way to build web UI. It seems the only benefit left on the json/ajax side is data-refreshing without reloading the page, at the cost of complex data processing in javascript. If I cut off json/ajax, I'm both cutting off the benefit & the javascript work, which doesn't really appear to hurt much to me.

I especially do not like jquery. I think JQuery is like a fabulous promise, which always starts in an attractive way, but as the project grows more and more complex, as more jquery elements added weired javascript errors emerge here and there. Even if I use json/ajax, I will not use jQuery anyway.

What do you think about it? Will you continue to work on json/ajax when using JSF?

Comment: JSON is a data format, AJAX is a technology. What do you mean with json/ajax?  AJAX is implemented in the most JSF components and the usage is mostly transparent. So you will (be able to) use AJAX, but without writing (to have to write) javascript code. Because most AJAX-calls are transparent, you don't have to think about JSON.

Comment: Your question is ambigous !. In most of the cases, you need to use ajax with JSF. you need to reload some data or hide/show a component. It all depends on your requirements.

Comment: Um.. apologies for being ambigous. I mean to use AJAX together with JSON.  Thanks very much for your explanation. So I'll not explicitlely write AJAX myself.